# Is it possible to use 2011 iMac as display for Windows 7 PC with DVI?

Tags: display, imac, windows, target-display

I've seen this question asked before but the answers either didn't quite seem to address the question, or were very old so I'd like to see if there's any way to do this today.

I have a mid-2011 iMac that does support Target Display Mode, but since I want to connect it to a Windows (7 Home) PC I understand TDM to be irrelevant and it won't work.

So, is there in fact any way at all to physically connect my iMac and use it as the display for my Windows PC?  A software solution won't do since this PC is almost exclusively for gaming and decent performance is required.  My video card is a GeForce 1050ti and has DVI and HDMI options on it.  I know this is a long shot but... is it possible at all?

Comment: Which "questions" are you referring to that are either insufficient or outdated?

Comment: Well for starters, the question linked as already being an answer to my question.  It seems to focus largely on software solutions, and the hardware solutions presented were confusing and unclear on if they are actually a workable solution or not.  It relies heavily on assumptions and conjecture, but has no hard & fast first-hand evidence.  It's also over 2 years old, though I found others that were much older.  With this kind of technology things can change any day with a new product coming to market etc. so I felt it worth checking.

Comment: TL;DR for the dupe:  Unless you connect the TB port on your laptop to the TB port on your iMac, it will not work.

Comment: This isn't about using a laptop.  I guess I didn't specify that... and it has no TB or I wouldn't have been asking the question in the first place.  But I've decided to abandon the whole idea anyway.